# Logging partially working in the application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, log4net

In my WPF application, I am using log4net for logging. This application implements several pages. My problem is that logging work from first page. Any other pages that user navigates to, nothing goes into log file. I am not getting any exception either.

Here is how its setup in my `app.config`:

```
<log4net>
    <!-- Define some output appenders -->
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="..\Logs\%property{LogName}.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>

      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
        <loggerToMatch value="MyWPFApplicationLog" />
        <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>

    <appender name="MyWPFApplicationAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="../Logs/MyWPFApplication.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="1" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="MyWPFApplicationLog">
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="MyWPFApplicationAppender" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

Then I have following in `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

In all the classes where I want to do logging, I have following declared.

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("MyWPFApplicationLog");
```

After that I just use logger.Info , logger.Error method in various places in class. From first page every thing is getting into `MyWPFApplication.txt` file but nothing from any subsequent pages. What's strange is that in Logs folder, I do see that there is another file (null).txt getting created but its empty. Do you see anything here that I may be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical explanation is that you have a different logger name in your other classes. Check if the name is idd MyWPFApplicationLog. If so your best option is to enable log4net debugging to see if your logger is working/crashed. In your web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>

...

    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
            <listeners>
                <add 
                    name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                    initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

[Log4net FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html)